# Чем тестировать highload?

Tags: highload, веб-программирование

К примеру, есть некое веб-приложение, над которым вы долго и упорно трудитесь с целью сделать сделать его максимально производительным. Думаю, рано или поздно, любой разработчик задается вопросом: "А что, если этот аппликейшн будет юзать одновременно 1k/10k/100k пользователей?". Именно в такой ситуации я сейчас нахожусь. В связи с чем и спрашиваю - каким инструментом воспроизвести нужную нагрузку на сервер? Каким образом выявлять узкие места? (кроме профайлера) В приложении очень много фронтэнда, js кода, база данных - postgresql.

Comment: Способ, в общем-то, только один - натравить на тестовый сервер (сервера) другие сервера, имитирующие пользователей в том количестве, в котором позволяет сеть, и смотреть метрики. Бутылочное горлышко может не проявлять себя на изолированных тестах или тестах со слабой нагрузкой (например, где-то происходит лок файла, который не заметен в процессе обычного тестирования, но будет дико тупить на десятках запросов в секунду), впрочем, такое тестирование тоже не обеспечит стопроцентного покрытия всех проблем.

Comment: Вообще, конечно, есть специальные компании с уже существующей инфрастуктурой под это дело ([пример](http://loadimpact.com/), сам не пользовал, но обещают некоторое количество бесплатных тестов), но я так понимаю, здесь имеется в виду меньший масштаб.

Comment: А как сымитировать активность пользователя? Ведь сценарии их работы должны быть уникальными, правильно?. Не использовать же API и на каждый сценарий свой отдельный код? Вероятно уже есть софт для того, чтобы записать сценарий и воспроизводить его параллельно другим? К примеру, Selenium может такое? И подходит ли?

Comment: 100k — это к инвестору пора )

Comment: @Андрей Таланин, отдача статики - это уже, обычно, дело не вашего приложения, а веб-сервера, и мерять ее не имеет большого смысла, основная задача - померять отдачу "тяжелой" страницы (т.е. не имеет смысла тестировать аякс-запросы, у которых есть страницы-аналоги, выполняющие ту же логику или больше), поэтому можно обойтись и курлом на коленке, либо поискать в гугле emulate user visit - там много левых ссылок, но есть и [такие](https://usu.li/simulate-real-users-load-on-a-webserver-using-siege-and-sproxy/).Selenium я бы не советовал из-за того, что нагрузка пойдет на браузер, а не на реквесты

Comment: IMHO, не надо городить огород раньше времени (см. "преждевременная оптимизация"), а для начала пройтись по всем доступным снаружи без регистрации/авторизации URL простым [apache benchmarks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

Comment: @Андрей Таланин, да и сценариев, как таковых, нет (это задача acceptance testing/bdd): деzтельность пользователя представляется просто как запросы разных страниц. Да, зачастую его предварительно надо авторизовать и сделать пользователей для всех видов страниц (если у юзера и админа в /dashboard непересекающиеся данные, то надо, конечно, тестировать оба случая), но после этой подготовки остается только швырять в сервер однотипные запросы. И нет ничего мегастрашного, если coverage не стопроцентный: если обновление любой настройки сводится к одному запросу в бд, то теста одной будет достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала можно с ab начать. Это служба идет вместе с [apache-utils](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/apacheab.htm). Там и конкурентные запросы и мини ддос можно имитировать. Поиграться на пару вечеров хватит)

Comment: ab одна из худших утилит для тестирования, которая морально устарела. Она использует один поток, поэтому больше 300 RPS редко удается выжать, хотя сама апликуха может легко тянуть 3k напр.

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv, моему сообщению более 3-х лет, и уже тогда я написал что с этого стоит начать, но не считать это серебряной пулей)

Answer (score 1):

Ну элементарно, если это веб приложение, значит по каким-либо интерфейсам Вы можете до него достучаться, а значит можете создать скрипт, который по крону эмулировал действия пользователей. Например, Вы можете менять количество запросов к приложению в зависимости от времени суток или других факторов.
Если же Вы собираетесь выпускать приложение в массы, то можно запросто организовать бета тестирование, которое помогло бы оценить хотя бы часть нагрузки. А еще плюсом будет то, что тестеры найдут баги, которые Вы успеете исправить до продакшена. 
Есть масса методов, но я не могу рассказать Вам подробнее, так как не знаю хотя бы примерное предназначение и вид приложения.

Comment: Личный кабинет игрока для клиент-серверной MMORPG. Заказчик как обычно, сам не знает чего хочет. Говорит что будет убербольшая нагрузка, просит протестировать корректность работы в условиях highload. Бета тест предполагается, но до этого нужно еще что-то предпринять.

Comment: Ну так и протестируйте ab, не вижу никаких проблем. Он же умеет прикидываться пользователем (см. -H, -C), POST проталкивать, и т.д. А уж на какие URL его натравлять это вам видней.